# Navigation View in Modal View

Tags: iphone

I am new to modal views and cant seem to get a navigation view display in a modal view.

How do I build a navigation view in the modal view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As sha stated:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Comment: `presentModalViewController` is deprecated as of iOS6. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507455/a-lot-of-functions-are-deprecated-ios-6

Answer (score 4):

You can use a navigation controller *as* a modal view controller.

```
[parent presentModalViewController:myNavigationController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

You create a UINavigrationController, then add UIViewController to it, then you present navigation controller with `presentModalViewController`