# present modal a ViewController inside navigationController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I  have a view(which inherits the navigationController property) but when I click an image inside this video I need to present a viewController modally.

Looking in here: [Navigation View in Modal View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477809/navigation-view-in-modal-view) I did this way:

*I created a new navigationController having as root the view that I need to present and presented modally my new navigationController**

```
moviePlayer = [[[CustomMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithPath:path1] autorelease];
navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:moviePlayer];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationController1 animated:YES];
```

Well here it is-This is how my screen looks like before presenting modally the new navigationController.
[image]

then I do this:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationController1 animated:YES];
```

an present my navigationController.

And when I dismiss the navigationController my screen looks like here:
[image]

My header and footer dissappear.Any solution for this.Thank you!

Comment: [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationController1.view animated:YES]; insted of assign your navigationController assign it`s view...as above..n check

Answer (score 0):

I have also same problem like this, what i done is, you can set modalview controller on tabbar contrller instead of navigation controller.

**Edit**
Instead of `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationController1 animated:YES];` write `[tabBarController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];`

Comment: please write some code in order to make it clear.Thank you very much.

Comment: `[tabBarController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];`

Comment: I done this  [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];  but nothing happens.Any idea why?

Comment: i have done this things which works for me i think you have to review your code why this happen and do accordingly.

Comment: But I think it should work, because I inherit a tabBarController....otherwise I shouldnt have it:)