# A Lot of Functions are deprecated - iOs 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, deprecated, ios6

I have a few functions that are deprecated since iOs 6.
Maybe this'll be helpful for others who also just updated to iOs 6.

```
    [self presentModalViewController:pNewController animated:YES];
 presentModalViewController:animated is deprecated since iOs 6

 Autosynthesized property 'String' will use synthesized instance variable '_String', not existing instance variable 'String'

Autosynthesized property 'phonenumber' will use synthesized instance variable '_phonenumber', not existing instance variable 'phonenumber'


 Deprecated: Group Table View Background Color is deprecated in iOS 6.0.
```

Could anyone help me how to fixed it so there wont be any deprecated functions in my project.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is the full warning message (posted for Google finding this thread with quotes around the search) 'presentModalViewController:animated:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
[self presentModalViewController:pNewController animated:YES];
```

can be replaced by

```
[self presentViewController:pNewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The background of this change can be seen on WWDC 2012 video session #236, the evolution of view controllers on iOS.

Answer (score 9):

click on the method which is deprecated. in the right column `Quick Help inspector` you can see the Quick Help from the Apple docs.
There is also a recommandation to use updated or alternate methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Open the .storyboard file or .xib file in "Source Code" mode.

Find and remove this line:

```
<color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="groupTableViewBackgroundColor"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with the last one: it means that the color GroupTableViewBackgroundColor is no longer supported in ios6. You probably used this in your xib files somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
[self presentViewController:object animated:YES completion:NULL];

[object dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```