# Make the app iOS 6.0 compatibale

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, iphone-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to develop or migrate apps for iPhone 5 screen resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395200/how-to-develop-or-migrate-apps-for-iphone-5-screen-resolution)

I have an app which was targeted for iPhone 3/3G and iPhone 4(retina) basically (using iOS SDK 5.0). Now i want to port it to iPhone 5. I have Xcode 4.5.1 installed on my machine. Most of the UI implementation is done programatically without using any Xib file.

At this stage i don't understand what to do and from where to start :(

Please help me to get an way...thanks in advance :)

I am pretty new in iOS...

Answer (score 1):

You could try: the xib>File inspector>Use auto layout.

Try it on the simulator of iPhone 5.

Also your code might have some errors/warnings like these:

[A Lot of Functions are deprecated - iOs 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507455/a-lot-of-functions-are-deprecated-ios-6)

You should fixe that, and then if it all works you're done

Comment: thanks :) but most of the UI implementation are handled programatically here no xib files :(

Comment: I tried to look for it, but i cant find it..

Answer (score 0):

As you are generatig the UI elements programatically, you might also want to try writing conditional statements for iPhone 5 screen.

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    //code for generate UI elements for iPhone 5 screen.
}
```