# Why does this code crash in iOS 5.1 but not iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This code is called from inside my Navigation views inside my Settings tab. It crashes on the last line in iOS 5.1 but **NOT** iOS 6. Why?

```
else if (indexPath.section == 0 && [[settingsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Unlock Premium Features"])
    {
        InAppViewController *inappController = [[InAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InAppViewController" bundle:nil];
        inappController.titleString = @"Upgrade to Pro.";
        EditNavController *navController = [[EditNavController alloc] initWithRootViewController:inappController];
        [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
    }
```

It crashes on:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:NO];
```

Here is the crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named NSLayoutConstraint'
```

Comment: Any particular crash message/stack trace/anything?

Comment: Does it crash on `presentModalViewController` line?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the other way around? 'presentModalViewController' is deprecated in iOS 6. It can be replaced by presentViewController:animated:completion. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507455/a-lot-of-functions-are-deprecated-ios-6)

Comment: @leanne, 'deprecated' doesn't mean 'broken' - it means 'we're gonna break it in the next release' ;-j

Comment: Yeah, sorry - that was a 'duh' moment...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you are using autolayout (if you created a new nib its on by default) in the view being presented, it will crash because auto layouts were only introduced in ios 6. [image: this is how to disable it]
<sub>(source: [raywenderlich.com](https://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/smat-disable-autolayout-480x242.png))</sub>

Comment: Thank you for showing how to disable it. It was one stupid button on my view that had the checkmark and it was crashing my whole setup. THANKS!

Comment: Still have to wait 2 minutes it says. Don't worry, I will. :)